# Render game objects in android app

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Is there a way to render game objects in android app by using game engine ?

I have tried using unity but the problem is that, it require to export app as jar and use that lib in game development.
What I am trying to accomplish is to develop app using android studio and render game components which are built using game engine.

so Is it possible to do that and if yes which tool to use?